# How to store a string at a specific address in Assembly language?

Tags: assembly, mips

Hi I was wondering how you could store a null-terminated string at a specific address, such as 0x10000100 in Assembly?
Thanks

Comment: The simplest way would be rep movs. You'll need to specify the length explicitly though, null termination is just a common convention in some languages.

Comment: How can I get the length of the string before I even store it? I would think to use REPNE SCASB for finding the length?

Comment: Yep, here's a code example for that - http://x86info.blogspot.co.il/2009/06/string-instructions-scasbscaswscasdscas.html

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it to work by just using lui $v0, 186A1. 186A1 would be the hexadecimal of 100001 which is the address I need it to be stored at. Right?

Comment: `$v0` is MIPS, lets tag it that way to get better answers.